# How to run the a shell script as background process and move on with next script without waiting for completion of first

Tags: bash, shell, background-process

I have below scripts ready with me -

*1.sh*:

```
echo "Good"
sleep 10
echo "Morning"
```

*2.sh*:

```
echo "Whats"
sleep 30
echo "Up"
```

*script1.sh*:

```
sh1.sh &
sh2.sh &
```

*script2.sh*:

```
echo "Hello world"
```

*Requirement*:

Execute `script1.sh` and do not wait for its completion or failure i.e., let the script run in background As soon as `script1.sh` is triggered the very next second execute the `script2.sh`.

```
./script1.sh 
./script2.sh
```

*Challenge*:

`./script2.sh` keeps on waiting for completion of `. ./script1.sh`.

Like `./script2.sh` I have lot of scripts to be run one after another but they should never wait for completion of `./script1.sh`

Thanks,
B.J.

Comment: use `&` to send script1 to the background `./script1.sh & ./script2.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Just as youdid in `1.sh`, you should append `&` after `script1.sh`:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
./script1.sh &
./script2.sh
exit 0
```

This will create a background process of `script1.sh` and continues in the main thread with `script2.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it a good practice not to leave background processes (unless they are long running servers, daemons, etc.). Better to make the parent script wait for all the children. Otherwise, you might have lot of orphan processes, which may use resources and have unintended consequences (e.g., open files, logging, ...)

Consider

```
#! /bin/bash
script1.sh &
script2.sh
script3.sh
wait    # wait for any backgrounded processs
```

One immediate advantage is that killing the main script will also kill running script1 and script2. If for some reason the main script exit before all background childs are terminated, they can not be easily stopped (other then killing them by PID).

Also, using ps/pstree will show system status in clear way